# How to compare observed distribution to sampled distributions, using cumulative distibution function?

Tags: r, sample, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a distribution of observed measurements and I want to compare it to sampled distributions, using R. 
I have a program that samples distributions, according to a certain low of probability / constraint.

Suppose I have:

- $m$ observed measurements
- two sets of $n$ samples of $m$ measurements

I'd like to compute:

- the average cumulative distribution function (a-cdf) of  the first set of samples (its value at each evaluation points is the mean value of the cdf of each sample at this evaluation point, and the evaluation points are the pooled $n\cdot m$ measurements)
- the 95% envelope of the first set of samples
- the spatial distribution index (sdi) of my observed measurements using the second set of $n$-samples. To compute the sdi, we compute all the maximum differences between the cdf of each new sample and the a-cdf, and the maximum difference between the observed cdf and a-cdf. That makes $n+1$ points, and the sdi is the rank of the observed difference among the $n+1$ differences.

I'd like to know if thoses function exists in R, and if not, what would be the smartest way to implement them. 
Hope i'm clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ecdf`, `quantile` and `rank` functions
to do this.

```
# Sample data
n <- 10
m <- 50
observed <- rnorm(m)
set1 <- matrix(rnorm(n*m),nc=n)
set2 <- matrix(rnorm(n*m),nc=n)

# Average cumulated distribution function of the first set of samples
ecdfs <- apply(set1, 2, ecdf)
acdf <- function(u) mean(sapply(ecdfs, function(f) f(u)))
acdf <- Vectorize(acdf)

# 95% envelope
alpha <- .025
x <- unique(sort(set1))
y <- sapply(ecdfs, function(f) f(x))
y <- apply(y, 1, quantile, c(alpha, 1-alpha))
lower <- approxfun( x, y[1,], method="constant", rule=2 )
upper <- approxfun( x, y[2,], method="constant", rule=2 )
curve(upper(x), xlim=c(-3,3))
curve(lower(x), add=TRUE)
curve(acdf(x), add=TRUE, lty=3)

# Rank of the observed sample 
# among the maximum differences
difference <- function(u) {
  max( abs( ecdf(u)(c(x,u)) - acdf(c(x,u)) ) )
}
sdi <- apply(set2, 2, difference)
sdi <- c( difference(observed), sdi )
sdi <- rank(sdi)[1]

# If you were to write a function to do this,
# it would return the following
list(
  acdf  = acdf,
  upper = upper,
  lower = lower, 
  sdi = sdi
)
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent, this is a great answer, very complete and useful. Would you know by the way if the Ripley's K function (computed from all couple of distances) has been implemented in R? Thanks again. Jeannot

Comment: I have a small question about your answer: why do you use 2 differents methods for computing the envoloppe and the acdf? would'nt it be equivalent to do :

lower = function(u) quantile(sapply(ecdfs, function(f) f(u)), alpha)
lower = Vectorize(lower)
?

Comment: There is no particular reason: 
pre-computing the quantiles may be slightly faster,
but the two approaches should be equivalent.
(After adding the missing `method="constant"`, they are now equivalent.)

Comment: Hi Vincent, could you explain me your "difference" function please? what's the "x" variable? thanks

Comment: `x` contains the data from `set1`.
We want to compute the maximum difference between 
`ecdf(u)` and `acdf` (these are functions, not vectors). 
Since these are stepwise constant 
functions, it is sufficient to evaluate them at each jump:
`x` contains the jump points of `acdf`
and `u` those of `ecdf(u)`,
so I evaluate both functions at `c(x,u)`.